# Having an Error with STATIC_ROOT when using heroku in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You’re using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

Having this error despite me having set the STATIC_ROOT:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

Answer (score 0):

Check the static file root. If it's on correct location. For heroku try to put that file on git. I am assuming it's a blank directory so it's not being pushed to git repo. Put .keep kind of file and add/commit and try. Hope it will solve your issue.